# Не отправляется сообщение в чат

Tags: python, django, websocket, chat, messenger

Создаю мини мессенджер, и пытаясь отправить сообщение в чат ничего не происходит.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чем проблема... И скорее всего думаю, что проблема тут.

**Consumers.py**

```
import json
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Message
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def fetch_messages(self, data):
        messages = Message.last_10_messages()
        content = {
            'messages': self.messages_to_json(messages)
        }
        self.send_message(content)

async def new_message(self, data):
    author = data['from']
    author_user = User.objects.filter(username=author)[0]
    message = Message.objects.create(
        author=author_user,
        content=data['message'])
    content = {
        'command': 'new_message',
        'message': self.message_to_json(message)
    }
    return self.send_chat_message(content)

async def messages_to_json(self, messages):
    result = []
    for message in messages:
        result.append(self.message_to_json(message))
    return result

async def message_to_json(self, message):
    return {
        'author': message.author.username,
        'content': message.content,
        'timestamp': str(message.timestamp)
    }

commands = {
    'fetch_messages': fetch_messages,
    'new_message': new_message
}

async def connect(self):
    self.room_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
    self.room_group_name = "chat_%s" % self.room_name

    # Join room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

    await self.accept()

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

# Receive message from WebSocket
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json["message"]

    # Send message to room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name, {"type": "chat_message",
                               "message": message},

    )

async def send_message(self, message):
    self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))

# Receive message from room group
async def chat_message(self, event):
    message = event["message"]

    # Send message to WebSocket
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))

async def send_chat_message(self, message):
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': message
        }
    )
```